# Counting principles question - team photo

Tags: probability

A rugby team consists of 8 forwards, 7 backs and 5 subs. They all line up at random in one row for a picture. What is the probability that:

a. the forwards are all next to each other?

b. no two forwards are next to each other?

I'm stuck on both bits. There are 20! ways to arrange them. There are 12 ways that the forwards can be together, so I know I have to multiply the probability that they are all together by 12 (assuming I'm correct, counting principles has yet to click in my head).  How do I get the probability that they are all together though?

Comment: Be careful not to mix models. The number of ways to arrange the players is $20!$ only if you care exactly which player is in each place in the row, not just whether that place is occupied by a forward, back, or sub. The number of ways to group all the forwards together is $13$ only if you _do not_ care exactly which player is in which place. If you took the ratio of those numbers as a probability, your answer would be wrong by a factor of $8!$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\textbf{Assuming that each person is distinct}$

a. Treat the 8 forwards as one group. They can be arranged together in 8! ways. Including the other 12 units, there are 13 units to arrange, done in 13! ways. So the arrangements with forwards together= $8!*13!$. Total arrangements= 20!.

Probability of forwards being together, therefore, is $\frac{8!13!}{20!}=\frac{1}{9690}$.

b. Arrange the other 12 people first. This can be done in 12! ways. Now, we can imagine the 12 people to be the number 1, and the spaces between them be commas:

,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,

As you can see, there are 13 commas, and so 13 gaps to insert the 8 forwards. Permuting hem so that they fit into the gaps: $\binom{13}{8}*8!$. Arrangements with the forwards separated therefore= $\binom{13}{8}*8!*12!$.

So probability of them being separated= $\frac{\binom{13}{8}*8!*12!}{20!}=\frac{33}{3230}$, as required.

NB: I believe this only applies if the forwards, back and subs are meant to be distinct (which they should be).

$\textbf{Assuming that the backs, forwards and subs are not distinct}$

a. Total arrangements=$\frac{20!}{8!7!5!}$. If the forwards are all together and they are not distinct, then it follows that there is only 1 arrangement for them when treating them as a unit. There are 13 units to arrange, of which there are 7 identical backs and 5 identical subs. Therefore, arrangements with forwards together= $\frac{13!}{7!5!}$.

Probability of the forwards being together= $\frac{\frac{13!}{7!5!}}{\frac{20!}{8!7!5!}}=\frac{1}{9690}$

b. As before, arrange the backs and the subs first: $\frac{12!}{7!5!}=792$.
There are 13 gaps, choose 8 of them to insert the forwards: $\binom{13}{8}$
Arrangements with the forwards separated therefore, is: $\frac{\binom{13}{8}*12!}{7!5!}$

Probability of the forwards being separated= $\frac{\frac{\binom{13}{8}*12!}{7!5!}}{\frac{20!}{5!7!8!}}$, which again gives the same answer.

Comment: Interestingly, it appears it doesn't matter whether the backs, subs and forwards are distinct or not- could someone perhaps explain why?

Comment: Nice answer, and of course it makes sense (as you say) to assume the players are distinct.  Since all we care about is how the 3 types of players are arranged, though, we could put masks saying F, B, S on the players first and then start arranging them.  As long as you're consist in your counting, which you were, you'll get the same answer.

Comment: Oh I see, fair enough. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are $13!8!$ ways to arrange them when all the forwards are next to each other, an easy way to think about it is just think about the line of forwards as one big person, and then you have a row of 13 people to arrange, and the inner arangement of the big forward person.

For the prob, in general the probability of event $A$ in $\Omega$ is $\frac {|A|}{|\Omega|}$ therefore the probability here is $$\frac {13!8!}{20!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

For part a), think of the forwards as one blob, and then count the number of ways to arrange 13 "people", and then multiply by the number of ways to arrange the forwards in their spots.

For part b), first count how many ways to arrange the other players, and then multiply by the number of ways to arrange the forwards in the gaps that are left.

Comment: number of ways to arrange other players would be $12!$? Not sure how to do the next bit.

Comment: See Sherlock Holmes' answer (where he assumes the players are distinct) to see how to finish this.

Answer (score 0):

ad a) Your are missing one position of ordering the 8 forwards. The number of positions from 8 to 20 are $20-8+1=13$.

And the 7 backs and 5 subs can be ordered in ${12 \choose 5}$ ways. Thus you have to multiply 13 by ${12 \choose 5}$.

Edit:

And the number of total possible arrangements are $\frac{20!}{5! \cdot 7! \cdot 8!}$

Answer (score 0):

**Answering A:**

Total number of ways to arrange them: $(8+7+5)!$

Number of ways to arrange them with the forwards next to each other: $13\cdot8!\cdot(7+5)!$

So the probability that the forwards are next to each other is: $\dfrac{13\cdot8!\cdot(7+5)!}{(8+7+5)!}=\dfrac{1}{9690}$